# Java connected to database, expects it to be in workspace

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse

Currently I'm trying to run the following code that is meant to connect to a MS Access Database. The Code appears to be loading the proper driver and connecting to the database, but whenever I try to execute the query, it is returning an SQL Exception, claiming that it could not find the database. However, it appears to think the database is in my Eclipse project workspace, particularly odd considering how it successfully connected to the database moments earlier. How can I specify where the program should be looking for the database?

```
public class DatabaseClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
             Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
             System.out.println("driver loaded");
        } //end of try
             catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
             System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
             System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }//end of catch
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:myDatabase");
            System.out.println("Connected to the database");
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String query = "<query goes here>";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            // handle Results here
        }//end of try
        catch (SQLException se){
             System.out.println("Not connected to database");
             System.out.println(se);
        }//end of catch

    }
}
```

Comment: database name should be a part of url, see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm

Comment: @DarshanMehta I thought `myDatabase` was the database name

Comment: ODBC bridge support has been deprecated, due to the fact that it's a complete pain in the code it get to work with 64bit platforms. I think [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) is one of the more common JDBC drivers used to access MS Access now days